# How to update a gunicorn flask application without turning it down

Tags: flask, gunicorn, vps

I have a flask application running with gunicorn hosted in a AWS Lightsail VPS, when I have to update the code from my flask application, I enter the VPS terminal, go to the project directory, run: git pull, pkill gunicorn, gunicorn app:app --timeout 900 -w 2 --daemon, and then the appliction is now running again with the new code updates, the problem is that the API is down the time between the commands pkill and gunicorn app:app, is there another approach to update the code without turning the server down?
ps: I'm using caddy as the reverse proxy, to turn my application public